# Text Message Broadcast Receiver with Other SMS Apps

Tags: java, android

One of my favorite apps lately has been GO SMS. The problem is one of it and handcents features. They block any notification of a text from the stock sms app. The problem is I have an app that also needs to be able to to know when an sms is received, and whatever they do it keeping that from happening. Is there anyway or any other intents that I can use to know when an sms is received? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway or any other intents that I can use to know when an sms is received?

Not really. The authors of that product have set their priority to the maximum value, AFAIK. There is no guarantee with any ordered broadcast that you will receive the broadcast, since somebody else might have a higher priority than you do.

Comment: So do they get the intent first, then stop it? And if I try to use the highest intent, they could get it first, or I could get it first is what you're saying?

Comment: @GQGK: "So do they get the intent first, then stop it?" -- via `abortBroadcast()`. "And if I try to use the highest intent, they could get it first, or I could get it first" -- in theory. In practice, they are at the highest known level. So, at best, it might be a "first one installed wins" sort of scenario. Again, there is no guarantee with any ordered broadcast that you will receive the broadcast, since somebody else might have a higher priority than you do.

Comment: So basically you're saying I'm out of luck on this one... Oh well. Thank you for the help!